# How to routing for mobile view in express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want to change the URL for mobile. www.example.com to m.example.com

I use isMobile function to detect device type.
I do not know what to do for routing. 
for example: m.example.com/index

please help me

in app.js

```
function isMobile(req, res, next) {
if ((/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(req.headers["user-agent"]))) {      
res.redirect('//m.' + req.host+ req.path);
} else {
next()
}
}


app.get('/',isMobile,routes.index);
```

If device is a mobile,i want to run routes.mobileindex. How?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Your logic seems to be correct. m.host.path is a new application or it's a view inside the same application. One more thing is you can configure nginx to get url redirect.

Comment: Error doesn't return and runs the index again.i want to run another view on mobile. it's a view inside the same application

Comment: IMO you can achieve the same by simply rendering another view if you isMobile function detects it as mobile device. one question though, the URL that you are redirecting to is a seprate application or it is in the same application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a separate view for mobile devices in the same application then it would be pretty straigh forward. it is a just a matter of creating another view file and you can apply your separate layout and `CSS` style to design it.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

function isMobile(req, res, next) {
  if (
    /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(
      req.headers["user-agent"]
    )
  ) {
    // Instead of redirecting to another view you can also render a separate
    // view for mobile view e.g. res.render('mobileview');

    res.redirect("/mobile/device");
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("index", {
    title: "Express"
  });
});

router.get("/device", isMobile, function(req, res, next) {
  res.json("normal view is rendered");
});

router.get("/mobile/device", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("mobile");
});
module.exports = router;
```

I have set a redirection here but this is not the best way if you are in the same application, because you can directly hit `/mobile/device` view, in that case you also need a middleware or can reuse the isMobile middleware to redirect to normal view. I would rather suggest to use `res.render('yourviewname')`

Hope this gives you an idea to proceed futher!

Comment: I use this method, but i want to use subdomain.<< m.example.com>>
I used express-subdomain and i defined m.localhost into hosts file, but didn't work